# Return elements between specific indexes

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

Imagine a situation where you have a list of elements for example:
`arr = ["h4", "p", "p", "h4", "p", "p", "p"]` and list of indexes where `h4` value
is:
`idx = [0, 3]`.
My goal is to print out values between these indexes, so the output will be:
`[["p", "p"], ["p", "p", "p"]]`.
In another words I want to print arr[0:3] and arr[3:] but I want to make it dynamic so for example with another array like
`arr2 = ["h4", "p", "p", "h4", "p", "p", "p", "h4", "p"]`,
`idx2 = [0, 3, 7]`
the output will be:
`[["p", "p"], ["p", "p", "p"], ["p"]]` (i.e. `arr2[0:3]`, `arr[3:7]`, `arr[7:]`).

**In every case `h4` value will always be at the index 0.**

I don't know if similar question was asked because I couldn't find and also I don't know if it is possible to do it. Maybe similar task is on leetcode, if someone knows something let me know.

Comment: What to you mean "where `h4` value is: `idx = [0, 3]`"? There is no variable named `h4`. The first element of `arr` has the *string* value `"h4"`.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `groupby` function from the `itertools` package you can group the term of the list by a custom criteria, `lambda term: term == 'p'`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for details.

```
import itertools as it

a = ["h4", "p", "p", "h4", "p", "p", "p", "h4", "p"]
 
grouped = [list(grp) for match, grp in it.groupby(a, lambda term: term == 'p') if match]
    
print(grouped)
```

Output

```
[['p', 'p'], ['p', 'p', 'p'], ['p']]
```